# My virtualenv does not work after installing zsh

Tags: virtualenv, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I installed zsh, oh-my-zsh. And made zsh as a default shell. But when I try to activate my virtualenv with

```
source bin/activate
```

There is no any effect. I mean no errors and also I am not in my virtual environment. Then I entered my earlier bash shell and tried activating but it did not also help?

**updated**
when I create new virtualenv it works well. Then how can I activate older ones?

Comment: How do you know it has no effect? Is it just that the shell prompt is not updated with the name of the virtual environment or is actually still the system environment being used? You can check this with `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` or `type python`.

Comment: After **source bin/activate** I cannot see virtualenv name on the left. And when I do **pip freeze** It lists me all packages in my system not in my virtualenv

Comment: Does `diff old_virtenv/bin/activate new_virtenv/bin/activate` provide any insights? As far as I know `virtenv` - at least older versions of it - just assumes that `bash` is being used. It may be that there are some constructs in `bin/activate` that do not work correctly with `zsh`.

Comment: In zsh there is no problem when I create new virtualenv.

Comment: Bash and zsh scripts are incompatible in many cases.

Answer (score 7):

By default, the zsh virtualenv plugin hides the virtualenv name.

```
vim ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/virtualenv/virtualenv.plugin.zsh
```

You'll see these in the file

```
# disables prompt mangling in virtual_env/bin/activate
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
```

Hash out `export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISBALE_PROMPT=1` and reload ZSH.

You'll see

```
New python executable in /Users/edd/.virtualenvs/test2/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/edd/.virtualenvs/test2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
/Users/edd/.virtualenvs/test2/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/edd/.virtualenvs/test2/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/edd/.virtualenvs/test2/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/edd/.virtualenvs/test2/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/edd/.virtualenvs/test2/bin/get_env_details
```

Try `virtualenv` to test.

You can get more information from
[here.](https://gist.github.com/heymonkeyriot/9a2f429caff5c091d5429666fa080403)

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from the same problem. This advice worked for me.